# Redirect to another action based on a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which has a value. I want to redirect to an action of another controller based on the value. I have used a simple if structure but I am not sure this is the cleanest way to do this. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

My current code is below.

```
// Get Search Results
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel searchViewModel)
    {
        var SelectedCategory = searchViewModel.SelectedCategory;
        var SearchText = searchViewModel.SearchText;

        if (SelectedCategory == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Artists", "Search");
        }
        else if (SelectedCategory == 2)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Albums", "Search");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Tracks", "Search");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not realise that site existed! Stack Exchange sites are appearing faster than I can keep track.

Agreed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a much better solution than what you already have provided. Only small tips here and there:

1. As a naming convention rule, local variables should be named with small case. See how SO syntax highlighter colored your local variable names as if they were class names.
2. If the only purpose of your `if ... else if ... else` is to do different things depending on the value of a variable (as it is in your code), it is better to use a switch statement.

Other than that, I don't think your code is in any way "bad".

**EDIT** By the way, if you are looking for a one-liner version (but less readable):

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel searchViewModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction(searchViewModel.SelectedCategory == 1 ? "Artists" : searchViewModel.SelectedCategory == 2 ? "Albums" : "Tracks", "Search");
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending a switch statement.

Thanks its not that the code is bad it just does not feel "right" to me.

Comment: I appreciate it @DavidBainbridge, I just can't think of any other "better" way. Of course you can get rid of magic strings but that would mean defining new variables (enums maybe) and that will overcomplicate the situation.

Comment: The `action` and `controller` are the wrong way round in your `RedirectToAction()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've answered too fast. Anyway, I suppose that `Category` is an enum (if it is not maybe it should be), so you can add an attribute like this:

```
public enum Category {
    [RelatedAction("Artists")]
    Artists,
    [RelatedAction("Albums")]
    Albums,
    [RelatedAction("Tracks")]
    Tracks
}
```

and then you will have only one line inside `Search` method:

```
return RedirectToAction(searchViewModel.SelectedCategory.GetRelatedAction(), "Search");
```

Comment: The `action` and `controller` are the wrong way round in your `RedirectToAction()`.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips: Or course, you are correct, but the idea is still same - easy to maintain, easy to extend. Anyway, Thank you, will fix it.

Comment: @blez No worries, it's an interesting solution.  I just thought I'd mention it for future reference for other MVC beginners reading this answer, just in case it wasn't apparent to them what wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement:

```
string action;

switch (selectedCategory)
{
    case 1:
        action = "Artists";
        break;
    case 2:
        action = "Albums";
        break;
    default:
        action = "Tracks";
        break;
}

return RedirectToAction(action, "Search");
```